# Show Material only while open mouth?

Tags: spark-ar-studio

How is it possible to show a Face material only while the mouth is opened? I dont know what to connect the Mouth Open Patch to. I have tried to search online but only found ways to play an animation while having mouth opened.

Comment: use the same detection to change material visibility

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple graph to solve your problem. If want to make a smooth transition, then you need to look at shaders patches(it is more advance stuff).

[image]